# Is there a word for the status of a team being 'home' or 'away'

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

A team can be 'home' or 'away' - but what is this status called?

At first I thought 'location' or 'venue' but this isn't right - the location is singular and the basis of what determines the 'home' or 'away' status.

ex:

- Team: Main Street Bruisers
- Mascot: Gorilla
- Score: 4
- *status*: Away

**edit**:

Thanks everyone for the input.  It's quite a tricky one.  The idea of 'hosting' is nice - but I'm not looking for a boolean kind of value - 'hosting? = yes' or 'hosting? = no' - more for a term that signifies the status of the field of play for a given team.

Comment: If its any help - home and away relate to which team is `hosting` - so it's the host vs visitor. you might want to think of a status for that.

Comment: I think **Status** itself sounds suitable.  May be you could consider using something like **Presently** (*Presently: Home* or *Presently: Away*), or **Whereabouts** (*Whereabouts: Home* or *Whereabouts: Away*), or something...

Comment: How about _Travel Status,_ with possible values _Home_ and _Visiting_ or _Visitor_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite you ruling it out, **venue** seems to be most commonly used even when there is no particular venue associated with it.

If you look at the [Home Advantage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_advantage) page on Wikipedia, which falls into the [Terminology Used in Multiple Sports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Terminology_used_in_multiple_sports) category, it repeatedly uses "venue" when talking about the location of a sports game. [Neutral Venue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_venue) also redirects to this page.

Comment: this has been open for awhile and i think this is the best answer.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose what you are looking for would be the name of the enumeration of home, away, and possibly neutral. In sports you could probably use the term *berth* since this is a term used for sports tournaments already, as in *this team has earned a berth in the finals*. If you search Google for "earned a berth" you will find multiple headlines using the word this way.

If we extend this idea to mean that there are two berths in a final, you could say that one berth is the home berth, and one is the away berth.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you another term for half of this topic. The team that travels to another city or venue, is usually known as the Visitors, The scoreboards at high school basketball games used to display the teams as Home and Visitors. The term for the home team, I am afraid is Home. Thus the phrases "home field advantage" or "home crowd ", and it even extends to play-by-play announcers who are a little too exuberant when describing a good play by his team. They are called "Homers"

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the question, though. What should go where *Status* is used in the question? Please take a moment to find upvoted answers to see the type of answer this site is looking for. We also provide [help on answering questions](http://$SITEURL$/help/how-to-answer). Answers should ideally include some sort of independent corroboration, [correctly referenced](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4981/18696).

Answer (score 1):

In U.S. sports (and sports reporting), games are for the most part identified as being home games or away games, but that simple and seemingly exhaustive split doesn't cover all of the venue possibilities in detail. At least five possibilities exist:

> 1. Team A plays Team B on Team A's regular home field.
> 2. Team A plays Team B on a different field in Team A's home region.
> 3. Team A plays Team B on Team B's regular home field.
> 4. Team A plays Team B on a different field in Team B's home region.
> 5. Team plays Team B at a truly neutral site at which neither side can claim a home-field advantage.

Under standard U.S. parlance, situations 1 and 2 are classified as "home games," situations 3 and 4 are classified as "away games," and situation 5 is classified as a "neutral-site game." You could argue that situation 5 involves what amounts to an away game for both teams—but for purposes of grading the quality of the victory by the winning side, it makes sense to distinguish it from (on the one hand) a victory achieved in front of a strongly supportive crowd and (on the other) a victory achieved in front of a passionately hostile crowd.

Since the *status* that the OP seeks a name for changes with each game, there is no reason why the OP couldn't replace it in the outline example with the word *game*, accompanied (for each particular game) by one of the three values "home," "away," or "neutral site."

However, I think that the word *site*, plus one of the three values "home," "away," or "neutral" works even better.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[locale](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/locale)*? *Oxford Dictionary Online* defines it as

> A place where something happens or is set, or that has particular events associated with it:
>   *her summers were spent in a variety of exotic locales*

The values for the criterion, *home* and *away* are terms of art within the sports field. While both would challenge someone who is totally unfamiliar with team sports or English, most individuals understand *home* means *home field or arena* and *away* means *someone else's field or arena*.

You might say

The *locale* of the Yankee game today is *away*. The *location* of the game is Detroit.

An alternative might be *[setting](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/setting?q=setting)*. Again, *ODO* defines it as

> The place or type of surroundings where something is positioned or where an event takes place

[Note: I am not suggesting that either of these offerings is a term regularly used in sports circles.]

Comment: locale and setting are both very closely tied to the location or venue which is what I want to decouple from

Comment: Maybe *Home Field?: Y/N*? Or even simply *Field: Home/Away*?

Answer (score 0):

Some sites I have seen generally just use "**home/away status:**" like [here](http://www.teamrankings.com/ncb/rankings/):

"(...)including team performance, home/away status, margin of victory, and other factors"

Comment: Answer has been edited to include a link